# Why page is getting redirected to different url than the specified url in wordpress.?

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded wordpress and uploaded it on the personal server..
I installed the wordpress and created a blog for website. It is working fine..
suppose my personal url is www.personal.com/wordpress/wp-admin/

Now I downloaded that blog from my personal server and made it live. But when I go for login that is www.example.com/wordpress/wp-login.php, it goes to my old personal dashboard (that is www.personal.com/wordpress/wp-admin/) instead of new dashboard www.example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/

I did Google much but I am not getting how to resolve this issue.
Please can anyone help me out from this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoTo your `wp_options` table and change `option_value` as shown in screenshot.

[image: image1]

Once done move to your admin dashboard via `wp-admin` and check the details under Setting and save once more as shown in screenshot.

[image: image2]